# Structured Tutorials

Tags: animation, rigging

New to Blender, and I'm starting to get to grips with the very basics. Youtube is great for learning but I find myself jumping all over the place and sometimes going down a rabbit hole.

Could anyone recommend a good structured training video (free or paid) - particularly on rigging and animation, from beginning to end

Thank you

Comment: [Blender Studio](https://studio.blender.org/training/?training_date_desc%5Bquery%5D=rigging) has the best training resources, and is very accesible.

Comment: on rigging character I think Darrin Lile and Sebastian Lague have made good tutorials

Comment: Thank you, thats a good start

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather than point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.